# Security problems with Silverlight 3 application

Tags: silverlight, security, iis, active-directory

I have a Silverlight 3 Application and for security I'm using Active Directory. For some reason that I can't explain whenever I access my app in the production servers the default browser authentication window pops up and I have to Authenticate two times!

Whats up with that? I checked IIS and everything seems fine!

Comment: Is the problem that you have to authenticate twice, or that you have to authenticate at all?  If your "production server" is using a FQDN (e.g. one with dots) then I'd expect at least one prompt because NTLM/Negotiate do not automatically authenticate in the Internet Zone.

Comment: Production Servers are part of the company Intranet. So I'm accessing it by its name. http://servername/myapp

Comment: Anyhow that was IT! I had my WCF endpoint pointing to the servers Extranet address. I don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As EricLaw said:

If your "production server" is using a FQDN (e.g. one with dots) then I'd expect at least one prompt because NTLM/Negotiate do not automatically authenticate in the Internet Zone

I had my WCF endpoint pointing to the servers Extranet address. I don't know how I missed that.